# Using Javascript in Underscore template

Tags: javascript, json, templates, underscore.js, momentjs

I need to display formatted date using my `underscore.js` template. I am using `moment.js`. My template is as follows:

```
// date, homeTeamName, homeTeamName values come from JSON object

<script type="text/template" id="fixtureTemplate">

    <% var matchDay = moment( %> + <%= date %> + <%); %>
    <h5> <% matchDay.format("MMMM-DD-YYYY"); %> </h5>

    <h5 class="red"><%= homeTeamName %> : <%= homeTeamName %></h5>

</script>
```

This does not render the template properly. Gives an error:

`underscore.js:1454 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

which is somewhere deep in `underscore.js`.

What's the proper syntax to put a `JSON` value inside code in the template, i.e. **how can I pass `date`, which comes from JSON object; into `moment()`**

Ideally, the code which I want to generate in template should look like this:

```
var matchDay = moment("2016-05-15T15:00:00Z"); // date should fill from JSON value
matchDay.format("MMMM-DD-YYYY");    //this should render on screen
```

Comment: I don't understand, you mean something like this?
`<% var matchDay = moment(date); %>`,
Shouldn't `date`  be in `<%= %>`, as it's coming from JSON object?

Comment: touchè, removed...

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and it got rid of the error, but the template is not rendering on screen.